# Should we convert all links to images to imgur and add a footnote pointing to the source?

Tags: discussion

Linking to external sites subjects to link rot.

Is it a good idea to host all such images on imgur and add a footnote citing the source of the image?

Comment: Convenient query for doing so: http://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/180619/cleanup-find-images-not-hosted-on-imgur. The number of images needing this isn't too large; I'd do it myself if I had the time right now.

Comment: @LoganM - Just for everyone else's convenience I have done some of them already. :) (also that's a pretty handy link too).

Comment: Keep in mind we should not be converting all NSFW links. Spoiler tags might be okay here, but *hyperlinking* to imgur is good too.

Comment: There were about 100-200(?) images that needed to be rehosted back in April when I made the query that Logan linked to in the above comment. The reason there are no more images from before April 2014 (besides the Death Note one that is too large to host on imgur) is that I edited all those posts and rehosted the images to imgur. I encourage other people to also do this.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but you should make sure you use the tool in the editor - As this will go through Stack Exchange's pro account and the images will not expire.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/

Answer (score 2):

We should convert all images to imgur links, but we should also add an **Important notice!** for image identification requests saying that the image link must be provided as it is on where the OP found it, so it would improve the chances of finding the source.

Images often have title, character or artist name in the url. Can't allow that to go to waste.